# "I'm suffered enough" vs "I've suffered enough"? What's the difference?

Tags: meaning, difference

I understand the *"I've suffered enough already."* but I'm not sure what *"I'm suffered enough already."* means and what's the difference between the two please?

I kind of understand the construct of *"I'm tired .."* but I can't figure out the meaning of *"I'm suffered .."* since there's also *"I've suffered .."*.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The difference is that nobody says 'I'm suffered [enough] [already]'. 'Tired' can be a participle or an adjective; 'suffered' cannot.

Comment: The "I'm suffered" is actually from some english teaching blog by a pro english teacher so I'm a bit puzzled here. I tried to search for it but got like just very few results.

Comment: Then that person's blog contains a typographical error. No native English speaker says "I'm suffered."

Comment: I agree with @Chemomechanics. No native speaker uses this construction, and the fact that you got very few hits when you searched for it is supporting evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you to say, "**I'm suffered enough**," that would mean ***others suffer you enough*** (i.e., others put up with you enough, tolerate you enough). It would not refer to your own suffering but to the suffering of others because of you, suffering you cause them. That's because it would employ the passive voice, so it'd be employing a transitive verb definition of "suffer" that in the active voice would make you the direct object, the cause of suffering, not the subject, the sufferer (see definitions 5, 6, and 7 of "[**suffer**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/suffer)").

Were you to say, "**I've suffered enough**," that would refer to your own suffering, not the suffering of others, that ***you've endured enough suffering yourself***.

**Example of Well-Known, Contemporary Use of "Suffer" Used Transitively from Wikipedia:**

> **[Suffer fools gladly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffer_fools_gladly#:%7E:text=The%20full%20verse%20of%20the,to%20suffer%20fools%20gladly%2C%20has)** *is a well-known phrase in contemporary use*, first
> coined by [Saint Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Paul) in his [second letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_to_the_Corinthians) to the Church at [Corinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corinth)
> ([chapter 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Corinthians_11)). The full verse of the original source of the idiom, [2
> Corinthians 11:19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Corinthians_11#Verse_19) ([KJV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KJV)), reads "For ye suffer fools gladly, seeing ye
> yourselves are wise." In its current
> usage, the meaning of the negative, *not* to suffer fools gladly, has
> been stated by the [Cambridge Idiom Dictionary, 2nd Ed. (2006)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/not-suffer-fools-gladly), as "to
> become angry with people you think are stupid".

Comment: For a citation of this unusual and slightly old-fashioned form, here's an example (using "he was suffered" rather than "I am suffered" but it's the same sense, "suffer" meaning "allowed to do something with tolerance rather than pleasure"): https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/he-was-suffered-to-do-so.2880786/